# get the value from a FileReader in Angular 2

Tags: angular, typescript, filereader

I have the following component that load a file and bind his content as string

```
    export class NgCsvComponent {

        @Input() csv: any;

        @Output() csvChange: any = new EventEmitter();

        public localCsv : any = '';

      constructor() { }

      changeListener($event): void {
        this.readFile($event.target);
      }

      readFile (inputValue : any) : void {
        let reader = new FileReader (),
              file : File = inputValue.files[0];
          reader.readAsText(file);    
        reader.onload = this.onLoadCallback;
      }

        onLoadCallback (event) {
            this.csvChange.emit(event.target["result"]);
        }
    }
```

the problem is that `this.csvChange`  is undefined inside `onLoadCallback` so how I could pass the result to some variable in my component?

I was search other similar [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30830268/how-to-make-filereader-work-with-angular2) but never get the result outside of onloadCallback function

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The problem is that the context is lost when you do:

```
reader.onload = this.onLoadCallback;
```

One solution is:

```
reader.onload = (e: Event) => {
    this.onLoadCallback(e);
}
```

Another one is:

```
reader.onload = this.onLoadCallback.bind(this);
```

Yet another one is:

```
onLoadCallback = (event) => {
    this.csvChange.emit((event.target as FileReader).result);
}
```

Bottom line. Make sure that the `this` context always remains inside your `class`.

Comment: Excellent implementation - particularly like the second solution. Thanks

Comment: I was trying to use `event.target.result` and always showed error until i changed it to `event.target["result"]`. Thank you!

Comment: @Akhil That's because `event.target` is typed as a `EventTarget` and this does not have the property `result`. You should cast it to FileReader first like: `(event.target as FileReader).result`