# Reading JSON file in angular 2 application

Tags: html, angular2-template, angular2-services

I have a file data.json which I want to import in my angular 2 application. I am getting file with HTML input tag.

```
<input type="file" (change)="onImport($event)"/>
```

in my typescript file I want to read this data.json file and store the content of file in JSON array. I have searched but couldn't find any way to read file or any library which could help me with this.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Use [`FileReader`](https://developer.mozilla.org/uk/docs/Web/API/FileReader) from the [File API](https://www.w3.org/TR/FileAPI/) and [`JSON.parse()` method](https://developer.mozilla.org/uk/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/JSON/parse) like:

```
  onImport(event) {
    var file = event.srcElement.files[0];
    if (file) {
        var reader = new FileReader();
        reader.readAsText(file, "UTF-8");
        reader.onload = function (evt) {
            console.log(JSON.parse(evt.target.result));
        }
        reader.onerror = function (evt) {
            console.log('error reading file');
        }
    }
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

I tried to apply @Stanislav solution but faced few issues. Eventually the following code worked

Ref: [get the value from a FileReader in Angular 2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39979809/get-the-value-from-a-filereader-in-angular-2)

- html code

`<input (change)=readJson($event);" type="file" />`

- component.ts code

  `readJson(event) {
      var file = event.srcElement.files[0];
      if (file) {
          var reader = new FileReader();
          reader.readAsText(file, "UTF-8");
          reader.onload = function (evt) {
              console.log(JSON.parse(evt.target["result"]));
          }
          reader.onerror = function (evt) {
              console.log('error reading file');
          }
      }
    }`

`event.target["result"]` is the part I modified.