# input file does not recognize listnerFunction in Angular 2

Tags: html, angular, input, listener

i´ve followed this simple example, how i could pass upload-file in my component.
[How to make FileReader work with Angular2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30830268/how-to-make-filereader-work-with-angular2)

My component.html file looks like this:

```
<div class="col-md-6">
     <div>
       Select file:
       <input type="file" (change)="changeListener($event)">
     </div>
</div>
```

and my component.ts file

```
import {Component, Input, EventEmitter, Output} from "@angular/core";
import {Router, ROUTER_PROVIDERS} from '@angular/router'
import { FormBuilder, FORM_DIRECTIVES } from '@angular/common';

@Component({

    moduleId: module.id,
    selector: 'edit-task',
    templateUrl: 'task.component.html',
    directives: [BlueFontDirective],
    providers: [ROUTER_PROVIDERS]
})
export class TaskFormat{


     //onChange file listener
    changeListener($event) : void {
        console.log('TRRRIIIGERT');
    }

}
```

And when i select some file i get error:

> browser_adapter.ts:78ORIGINAL EXCEPTION: TypeError:
>   self.context.changeListener is not a
>   functionBrowserDomAdapter.logError @ browser_adapter.ts:78
>   browser_adapter.ts:78ORIGINAL STACKTRACE:BrowserDomAdapter.logError @
>   browser_adapter.ts:78

**UPDATE**

I just tried it something else.
My html-template looks like this:

```
 <input type="file" (change)="fileChangeEvent($event)" placeholder="Upload file..." />
        <button type="button" (click)="upload()">Upload</button>
```

And when i select any file and click the Button "open" within selection-promt, i get error, too without to trigger something in my angular2-backend:

```
browser_adapter.ts:78 TypeError: self.context.fileChangeEvent is not a function
    at _View_TaskFormat0._handle_change_9_0 (TaskFormat.template.js:698)
    at eval (view.ts:374)
    at eval (dom_renderer.ts:308)
    at eval (dom_events.ts:16)
    at ZoneDelegate.invoke (zone.js:232)
    at Object.onInvoke (ng_zone_impl.ts:67)
    at ZoneDelegate.invoke (zone.js:231)
    at Zone.runGuarded (zone.js:128)
    at NgZoneImpl.runInnerGuarded (ng_zone_impl.ts:100)
    at NgZone.runGuarded (ng_zone.ts:216)
```

"FileChangeEvent" will be triggered, when i select any file, but a error will be thrown...

Comment: What version of angular are you using, the stable version of angular 2 doesn't have directives in the @component anymore .

Comment: within my dependencies i see: "@angular/core": "2.0.0-rc.1",

Comment: That's from the dark ages. You should upgrade. Hardly anyone will remember how things worked back then.