# how to read a file using Angular 2

Tags: angular

how can I read a file using Angular 2 without using a html view. for examples up to now they have provided an example like.

[How to make FileReader work with Angular2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30830268/how-to-make-filereader-work-with-angular2)

using

```
  <input type="file" (change)="changeListener($event)">
```

selecting a file using an input.

I want give my constant path for it without selecting the file from the view how can i do it ?

Answer (score 3):

For Security reasons, the browsers do not allow access to absolute path & file systems directly to Javascript. You can only read files using tags like you said

`<input type="file" (change)="changeListener($event)">`

And FileReader Api is just a more convinient way to do this.
So basically speaking you can't do what you want, at least without some really hacky tricks :)

Comment: thank you need to find and alternative way: also i can create a json file and import it into my component then I can use its data.