# Javascript Push - Undefined

Tags: javascript, xml, angular, typescript

I am trying to do something quite basic in Javascript and that is read through an xml file and push data into an array.  From all the searching i have done the syntax is just this.xxx.push(itemTobePushed).

However i am getting Cannot read property 'payrules' of undefined.

Its an angular5 project with typescript

**CODE**

```
payrules = []; // Create empty array

testXml(inputValue: any) {
    const file: File = inputValue.files[0];
    const myReader: FileReader = new FileReader();

    myReader.onloadend = function (e) {
      xmlLoader.parseString(myReader.result, function (err, response) {
        response.Kronos_WFC.Response.forEach(payrule => {
          payrule.WSAPayRule.forEach(name => {
            console.log('Pay Rule Name: ', name.$.Name); // This works fine and outputs a lits of payrules
            this.payrules.push(name.$.Name); // This fails with Cannot read property 'payrules' of undefined 
          });
        });
      });
    };
    myReader.readAsText(file);
  }
```

Comment: Print in the console `this` ;) you'll see it's not what you expect. Scopes in Javascript are often confusing at the beginning!

Comment: That means `this` is undefined, you can bind a new context with payrules property on each function called by forEach

Comment: Change `function (err, response)` to `(err, response) => `

Comment: OK Thanks guys for everyone's feedback.  I managed to get it working by looking at this post https://stackoverflow.com/a/34029588/3129691